# Почему Rotator меняет своё положение и как это исправить?

Tags: unity3d

Изучаю Unity3D. Пока просто разбираюсь с основами и интерфейсом. Хочу, чтобы камеру можно было крутить вокруг куба. Подсмотрел, что можно создать пустой объект, к нему привязать камеру и крутить её вокруг него. Но столкнулся с проблемой.

Здесь видно, что этот объект находится внутри куба

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если я вкладываю камеру в этот объект, то получается такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Данный объект переходит внутрь камеры. Не понимаю почему так происходит. Помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: @Yaroslav, спасибо большое. Напишите ответом ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На [Toolbar](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Toolbar.html) второй Control.....

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]